# Failure Message only for failing cases in jmeter

Tags: java, netbeans, jmeter, assertions, beanshell

I have added bean shell assertion in my scripts.

It shows the failure message for all the cases, even if it passed.

Below is my scripts

```
String response = new String(ResponseData);
if(${BoolValue} == true)
{
    Failure = !(response.contains("growth"));
    FailureMessage = "Projection values is showing in the response data for non-skill reports";

}
if(${BoolValue} == false)
{
    Failure = (response.contains("growth"));
    FailureMessage = "Projection values is not showing in the response data for skill reports";
}
```

I need to get Failure Message only if the case gets failed. Please let me know, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Failure before Failure Message assignment:

```
String response = new String(ResponseData);
if(${BoolValue} == true)
{
    Failure = !(response.contains("growth"));
    if (Failure) {
      FailureMessage = "Projection values is showing in the response data for non-skill reports";
    }

}
if(${BoolValue} == false)
{
    Failure = (response.contains("growth"));
    if (Failure) {
      FailureMessage = "Projection values is not showing in the response data for skill reports";
    }
}
```

BTW use should probably use Java conventions of variable name should start with lowercase letter as: `failure` instead `Failure`.